# As a newcomer I would like to say Thank You

Tags: discussion

It is immediately evident that ELU runs as well as it does, is as informative as it is and stays as courteous as it does because of the hidden contribution that goes on, constantly, behind the scenes.

Thank you, to all concerned.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English Language & Usage Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @BlackandWhite It appears okay to me. :)

Comment: What? You're clearly wrong. Everyone knows we're heartless critics, and not courteous at all: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/downvoting-newcomers-with-no-explanation-or-comment

Comment: @Nigel I have rolled back your edit. It wasn't necessary to ask that. This is already an accepted Q&A. Leave it as it is. If you have another question, please ask that in a new question.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for engaging! Forgive me for the false step; I will presently delete my previous comment. I appreciate your grateful approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Speaking on behalf of everyone on ELU,

## You're welcome! :)

It's newcomers like you who stick around to learn the site's culture that keeps the site working as it does.

Comment: I don’t think OP is making a question, and as such there is no need to post an  “answer.”

Comment: @Josh "you're welcome" isn't really an answer to the "question", but a response to "thank you". Always the buzzkill, eh, Josh? ;)

Comment: I feel like the downvotes here represent "No, you're not welcome". Hah! Weird. :)

Comment: haha and this is the reason this stack just works. Light Hearted, helpful, insightful, *generous* and not anal about the academic merits, cultural relevance or social impact of a question. It makes newbies like me (kinda) feel welcome to ask and encourages everyone to stick around.